# http.dart invalid argument for onError: Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as arguments

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I am new to Flutter and I'd like to understand what's wrong with my error handler:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
try {
  var response = await client.get('$endpoint/users/$userId');

  // Convert and return
  return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
} on HttpException catch (ex) {
  print('http');
  print(ex);
  print('exception');
  return null;
} on Error catch (error) {
  // code will go here
  print(error);
  return null;
}
```

The result is:

```
I/flutter ( 3103): Invalid argument (onError): Error handler must accept one Object or one Object and a StackTrace as arguments.: Closure: (HttpException) => Null
```

It is exactly the same as if I didn't do any `try/catch`, could anyone advise how should I do the Error Handler? From my understanding `(error)` here should be the "one Object", please correct me if I'm wrong. TIA!

Comment: Could you post a minimal, reproducible example?

Answer (score 6):

this is an [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) dependency bug and it was fixed in version 0.12.2, it should be resolved when you update your dependency.

Comment: This was indeed causing the bug and updating http from 12.1 to 12.2 fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch `Object` too. `HttpException` and `Error` do not cover all kinds.

```
    on Object catch (error) {
      print(error);
      return null;
    }
```

Comment: `catch (e)` is more idiomatic than `on Object catch (e)`.  The error in the question also isn't about an uncaught exception.